# Is it right for this kind of equivalence substitution when evaluate of limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is my question:  Let $\mathbb{R}^*:=\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}, x_0\in\mathbb{R}^*$, and $f: D\subset\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, with $x_0$ be a limit point of $D$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=0,$ and $f(x)\sim g(x),$ as $x\to x_0.$ Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^*$. Then, is it true that
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} (1+f(x))^{h(x)}=A\iff \lim_{x\to x_0} (1+g(x))^{h(x)}=A \ ?$$
Here the symbol $f(x)\sim g(x)$ as $x\to x_0$ means that there exists a function $\alpha=\alpha(x),$ such that $\lim_{x\to x_0}\alpha(x)=1, $ and $f(x)=\alpha(x)g(x)$ as $x\to x_0.$
I think it is true, but now I have trouble to verify it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\log A &= \lim_{x \to x_{0}}h(x)\log(1 + f(x))\\
&= \lim_{x \to x_{0}}h(x)f(x)\frac{\log(1 + f(x))}{f(x)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to x_{0}}h(x)f(x)\cdot 1\\
&= \lim_{x \to x_{0}}h(x)g(x)\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to x_{0}}h(x)g(x)\cdot 1\\
&= \lim_{x \to x_{0}}h(x)g(x)\cdot \frac{\log(1 + g(x))}{g(x)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to x_{0}}h(x)\log(1 + g(x))\end{aligned}$

So what you mention is question is correct and I have shown above why it is correct.